# how do i identify and check text using perl?

Tags: perl

I have xml data like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//ES//DTD journal  article DTD version 5.2.0//EN//XML" "art520.dtd" [<!ENTITY mmc1 SYSTEM "mmc1" NDATA APPLICATION><!ENTITY mmc2 SYSTEM "mmc2" NDATA APPLICATION>]><article docsubtype="fla">    <item-info><jid>JURO</jid><aid>10407</aid><ce:pii>S0022-5347(13)04374-7</item-info><ce:inter-ref xlink:href="http://download.journals.elsevierhealth.com/mmcs/journals/0022-5347/PIIS0022534713059089.mmc2.pdf" id="intref0010"><ce:bold>Abstract</ce:bold></ce:inter-ref><ce:inter-ref xlink:href="http://download.journals.elsevierhealth.com/mmcs/journals/0022-5347/PIIS0022534713059089.mmc1.pdf" id="intref0010">   <ce:bold>Abstract</ce:bold></ce:inter-ref>
```

There is a link is given for abstract text, this link generated by EITIY declaration "MMC\d" and data in

```
<pii>..</pii>
```

nw i check given link is correct or not by collecting two data from this code which eitiy declaration "MMC1".. and data in

```
<pii></pii>
```

in my code i collect this data. In this code first is mmc1 and S0022-5347(13)04374-7
and i remove '-' '(' ')' this in pii variable and add mmc1 into that. after i make like this "PIIS0022534713059089.mmc1" and check.

nw the problem is

the abtract text coming two times in a file so first abstract should contain "PIIS0022534713059089.mmc1" and second abstract should contain "PIIS0022534713059089.mmc2"
but if given wrongly first abstract text "PIIS0022534713059089.mmc2" and second abstract text "PIIS0022534713059089.mmc1" we identify and tell to user.

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

print "start..";

@files = <*.xml>;

open my $out, '>', 'output.xml' or die $!;

foreach $file (@files) {

    open (FILE, "$file");

    while (my $line = <FILE>) {
        if ($line =~ /(<ce:pii>)(.*)(<\/ce:pii>)/) {
            $pii = $2;
            $pii =~ s/\-//g;
            $pii =~ s/\(//;
            $pii =~ s/\)//;
        }
        if ($line =~ /\"(mmc)([1-5]{1})\"/) {
            my $count = $1 . $2;
        }
        if ($line =~ /$pii\.$count/) {
            print ".";
        }
        else {
            print $out("$file = wrong\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking how to make sure that each abstract appears in ascending order -- starting with `.mmc1`, then `.mmc2`, then `.mmc3`, and so on.  I'm going to guess also that the file may contain lots of different abstracts, so `ABSTRACT1.mmc3` might be followed by `ABSTRACT2.mmc1` and that should not signal an error. Right?

You can use a hash to keep track of the most recent `mmc` number seen for a particular abstract.  Then when you see a new `mmc` for that abstract, you can check it against the one you previously saw. Like this:

```
open (FILE, "$file");
my %last_mmc;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    ...
    if ($line =~ /"mmc([1-5])"/) {
        # Check that the mmc number is correct.
        $last_mmc{$pii} ||= 0;
        warn "incorrect mmc: $pii.$line" if ($2 != $last_mmc{$pii} + 1);
        $last_mmc{$pii} = $2;
        my $count = "mmc$2";
    }
    ...
```

Comment: the aim is whatever first found "mmc\d" should be first abstract and second "mmc\d" should be seocnd abstract and so on if not error msg..